# Is it possible that $X>Y$ almost surely and $F_X(c)=F_Y(c)$ for all $c$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have two random variables $X,Y$ which are further functions of $V,W$ that is $$X=f(V,W)$$ and $$Y=g(V,W).$$ Further, if I draw a value of $V$ and $W$ randomly then I know that $X>Y$ for all combinations of $V$ and $W$.

In this case is it possible that $F_X(c)=F_Y(c)$ for all $c$?

A possible problem:
Assume that $V$ and $W$ are exponential random variables with unit mean (parameter). Further assume that $$X=\frac{UV}{1+U}$$ and $$Y=min\left(V\left[1-max\left(0,1-\frac{a}{V}\right)\right],max(0,1-\frac{a}{V})VU\right).$$ Now for this case it can be shown that $X>Y$ for all possibilities of $U,V$. Further $$P(X\leq a)=P(Y\leq a)=1-2e^{-a}\sqrt{a}K_1(2\sqrt{a})$$ where $K_1(x)$ is the modified bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: Is this different than asking $X>Y$ almost surely then is it possible $F_X(c)= F_Y(c)$?

Comment: @clark sorry i dont understand what you said

Comment: By stochastic domination, $P(X\leq c) \leq P(Y\leq c)$. Can it ever be strict equality when $X$ is strictly greater than $Y$? Does this match your question?

Comment: @jdods perhaps it can match my question. But where is the answer?

Comment: @jdods i mean is there any specific condition under which this becomes equal?

Comment: @ZacharySelk made clear. It is for all $c$.

Comment: @ZacharySelk can we say something now?

Comment: This smells of the xy problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Take the region in $U,V$ space that makes $X\leq c$. Then $Y\leq c$ on this region as well. Now $Y$ could also be $c$ or lower elsewhere, but we want this to be a set of zero probability in order to make the cdfs match. 

So we require $P[(u,v) \mid f(u,v)>c, g(u,v)\leq c]=0$ for all $c.$ I'm having trouble coming up with an example, and an skeptical about it.

Comment: Indeed all the dressing up of the question with (U,V) is distracting at best.

Comment: @Did I have added an example for which $X>Y$ and $P(X\leq a)=P(Y\leq a)$

Comment: Is it true that the $a$ in $P(X\leq a) $ is the same as the $a$ that is used to define the random variable $Y$?

Comment: @Shashi yes it is same

Comment: @FrankMoses then that is just one specific $a$? So that is not an example where the distribution functions are equal for all values.

Comment: @Shashi that means at one particular point they can be same but not at all the points

Comment: @FrankMoses so even if your calculations are all right, your example is not an example of the claim which is clearly proven wrong in the answer given.

Comment: What @Shashi explained.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $X>Y$ and $F_X (c)=F_Y (c)$ for all c. Let r be a rational number. Let $A=\{X \leq r\}$ and $B=\{Y \leq r\}$. Then A is a subset of B. Hence $P(B\setminus A)=P(B)-P(A)=F_Y (r) -F_X (r) =0$ Thus $P\{Y\leq r<X\}=0$. This holds for every rational number r; taking the union over all possible values of r we get $P\{Y<X\}=0$ but $P\{Y<X\}=1$ by hypothesis. Hence, it is not possible to have such random variables and the variables $V,W$ have no role to play here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can understand your answer but I have posted one example where the CDF is same for both $X$ and $Y$. Can you please comment where I am doing it wrong?